# Enable PHP-GMP in Travis CI

Tags: php, travis-ci

I use Travis-ci for the automated testing of one of my PHP projects.
So far I was using the PHP 5.4 environment and everything worked fine.
After upgrading to the PHP 7.2 environment however I got the following error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_gmp.so'(tried:
 /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.2.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/php_gmp.so
(/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.2.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/php_gmp.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.2.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/php_gmp.so.so
(/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.2.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/php_gmp.so.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to to fix this by updating my .travis.yml file, so far without success

```
language: php
dist: bionic

sudo: true

php:
  - 7.2
# Doesn't work
#before_install:
#    - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
#    - sudo apt-get update
#    - sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp

install:
  - composer install

before_script: phpenv config-add phpconfig.ini
```

This is a link to the Github page of the project in question: https://github.com/BitcoinPHP/BitcoinECDSA.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `extension="php_gmp.so"` from the `phpconfig.ini` file and everything worked properly.